# Drupal: Views titles

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, preprocessor

I have a View that outputs a page. Under Basic Settings I set a "title". When I load the page, I see that title as the page title (at top of the browser) - all good.

How can I print this value out in the "Display output" .tpl file? The $title variable doesn't seem to hold any value here. Do I need to use a preprocess function?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does [`drupal_get_title()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_get_title/6) work?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the details of the full view  using

You can get the title of all the displays there

```
$view2=views_get_current_view();
$view2->display['default']->display_options['title'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the title than no need to write the .tpl file.

In views you will find header region and there you can add the global text are and by using it , you can add the title text over there.